# jQuery focusin / focusout - Triggering when page is updated programmatically - How to detect when *only* human focuses?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some simple code to check when inputs are focused in / out:

```
$(document).on(`mouseenter mouseleave focusin focusout`, `input, textarea, [type=checkbox], select`, async function (e) {
  
  if(e.originalEvent == undefined){
    return;
  }
....
```

When the page loads, a script runs to populate some of the inputs. Some of the inputs are generated dynamically, conditionally based on other input values, and then populated.

I don't want any activity based on non-human activity (i.e., a script creating / generating and populating fields)

On page load, the events have a populated `e.originalEvent` as though a human had performed this focus in / out event - However this is not the case, it's the script updating the page at load time, before the human has maniuplated the page.

So when the page loads, and fields are generated / populated, the even is triggering as though a human had performed the focus event (e.originalEvent is not `undefined`).

How can I test for a focus event only being from a human (mouse activity clicking in out of the input, or the tab key being pressed) and not when a script runs to update fields in the page?

(Notes: I already use `mouseeneter` and `mouseleave` and can see those as 'human' events. I have also tried `focus` and `blur` (same result), and note the jQuery documentation for focus: `An element can gain focus via keyboard commands, such as the Tab key, or by mouse clicks on the element.` None of these conditions are true, so there shouldn't be a script-based trigger?)

Thank you

Comment: Instead of trying to detect something you can't detect, make your content do the right thing regardless of what caused focus placement? Because right now you're actively trying to screw over people who rely on assistive technologies, and that's really not an okay thing to try to do.

Comment: The project is only ever viewed by me, for managing my own time... so I'm screwing myself over I guess? 

Comment: Sure, and in that case, why care about "automated focus"? You're the only one using it, it's always you and this problem isn't a problem.

Comment: I care because I'm learning a new technology and this approach seemed a nice way to animate and update my page - Except the documents for the technology don't seem to be correct.

Comment: Right, so the answer here is "you can't, because there is no such thing as 'a human' when it comes to elements receiving focus", the correct way to go about this is to write your form interaction in such a way that when a field receives focus, it does the right thing irrespective of what caused focus to be gained. You shouldn't try to do this on a real site, and if it's just toy code for learning, you should change your approach to write code based on the DOM's browser interaction model. Go _with_ the river, don't try to walk against it.

Comment: And in terms of the jQuery docs? `An element can gain focus via keyboard commands, such as the Tab key, or by mouse clicks on the element.`<-- This isn't true?

Comment: Of course it's true, but it would be a mistake to think that text says anything about human input. Keyboard and mouse events are just events: you have no way of knowing whether they were generated by code (page code, extensions, other apps on the same computer, virtual keyboard/mice, etc. etc), unattended real hardware (no humans involved), or an actual human using their HID; the only thing the browser knows is that events get triggered. If your fields can be focused, and they should do something on focus, make them do that in a way that makes sense no matter what triggered the focus.

Comment: I disagree here - The docs specifically stipulate a tab *key* and *mouse* click. So ignoring the human element, these events, following those definitions, shouldn't be triggered in the absence of hardware / wetware - But they are.

Comment: Your agreement is not required to make it true. JS can trivially create and dispatch keyboard and mouse events and the browser will act on them because it acts on events. That's how the DOM interaction model works.

Comment: The critical concept here is *events*. Per jQuery `Category: Events
These methods are used to register behaviors to take effect when the user interacts with the browser, and to further manipulate those registered behaviors.` * the user interacts with the browser* <-- has not occurred (in the session in question).

Comment: Now we're getting somewhere: no, _that_ sentence in the jQuery documentation is not true in the slightest. By design, the browser has no way to unequivocally determine whether an event was generated by a user or not. All it gets to see is the events themselves, which triggers handling of those events based on event type, and only event type. You could add your own details to a custom-generated event, so that your code can confirm that event is indeed code-generated, but there's nothing that lets you confirm that an event _wasn't_ code-generated.

Comment: `You could add your own details to a custom-generated event, so that your code can confirm that event is indeed code-generated, but there's nothing that lets you confirm that an event wasn't code-generated.` <-- I think that's the answer. Anything that was script generated could pass some metadata to test against.

Comment: it could, but now you're doing the _exact opposite of what you're asking_. You were not asking how to detect your own events as being programmatically generated. You were asking how to detect whether _any_ event was human generated. The first is trivial. The second is impossible. And note that even though the first is trivial, that does not cover "all events", it only covers "your events". You still won't be able to detect eents generated by code outside your control.

Comment: Yes - The exact opposite approach serves the functional requirement. When I roll a die, I either want a 6, or I don't want 1,2,3,4 or 5. Both serve the same logic. `You still won't be able to detect events generated by code outside your control.` <-- For conclusion, what events do you suggest are outside the control of the developer?

Comment: no, that's actively misreading: every event _that you generate_, you control. But you do not control any events generated by "not your code", e.g. jquery plugins, third party page scripts, browser extensions, etc. etc. You have no control over whether those include details when creating events.